# Django functions issue and urlconf confusion

Tags: django, function, blogs, categories

I couldn't place my question into one sentence.
I was following a tutorial to make a blog from scratch. But the tutorial predicted having all the categories, tags, months and years listings in separate templates.

I want to add a list of categories, a list of months and years on the main blog page.

So here is what I got. With this code, the list of categories is shown in the main page but only if you go to the blog/category url, and not in just blog/ where I want it to be.

```
    **(r'^$', list),**
    (r'^archive/(\d{1,2})/$', list),
    (r'^\d{2}/d{4}/$', month),
    (r'^([0-9]{4}/\d{1,2})/(?P<slug>.*)/$', detail),
    (r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', year),
    **(r'^category/$', category),**
```

I also tried:

```
    (r'^$', category),
```

but no luck.

This is the same code from the template in category.html and in list.html:

```
 {% if categories %}
        {% for category in categories %}
        <li class="cat-item"><a href="category/{{ category.name.lower }}/"
            title="{{ category.name.capitalize }}">
             {{ category.name.capitalize }}</a>
         </li>
         {% endfor %}
         {% endif %}
```

Views.py:

```
def category(request):
    return render_to_response('blog/list.html', {'categories':Category.objects.all(),},)
```

It was like this. I tried this, but no luck in def list:

```
return render_to_response('blog/list.html',{'posts':posts,
                                       'next':next,
                                       'previous':previous,
                                       'categories':Category.objects.all(),
                                       },)
```

How can I get what shows on blog/category to show on blog/ also?
Thanks.

Comment: `list` is a Python built-in function. I would not recommend naming your view list as it will shadow that built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type an url in your browser a request is sent to your server. Django then takes the url and matches it against it url patterns to determine the proper view. As soon as a view is found django stops matching and executes this view which in turn returns a response.

If you want to use your categories in different views you either have to to make sure that in every view the same `categories` context variable is provided to the template or, which is usually much better, [write a simple custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). For your categories this could look like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('blog/category_list.html')
def categories_list():
    return { 'categories': Category.objects.all() }
```

In the file 'blog/categoy_list.html' would then be the code that is currently both in 'categories.html' and 'list.html'. In these files replace it with.

```
{% load your_blog_tags %}
{% categories_list %}
```

You can use that then wherever you need a category list. Of course the same applies for years and month lists.

Comment: Ok, I did al that, but I still get nothing.

Comment: Do you have some `Categories` in your database? When you do `python manage.py shell` and then `import <your_blog_tags>` and `categories_list()` what do you get?

Comment: what do you mean by import <your_blog_tags> ? because I created a templatetags folder in my blog application folder, and inside I have these files: categories_list.py  categories_list.pyc  __init__.py  __init__.pyc .And the code is same as above. So I load categories_list in the template and have a {{ categories_list }} where I want it to appear. And yes I have created 3 categories in my database and they are shown on the blog/category page accordingly.

Comment: but if they are shown, then there is no problem!? with `import <your_blog_tags>` I mean `from templatetags.categories_list import categories_list`.

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks :) sorry it took a few days I forgot to tell :)